# Merge/Summarize date and time to x-minutes chunks

Tags: r, date, dataframe, datetime, merge

I’ve the following data frame (mydf) with UNIX-Timestamps:

```
1543748345000
1543760946000
1543752164000
1543720144000
1543752713000
1543781064000
1543753688000
1543765145000
…
```

(n = 200,000)

I convert these in date format, using:

```r
mydf <- as.POSIXct(as.integer(as.numeric(as.character(mydf)) / 1000.0),origin='1970-01-01', tz="GMT")
```

This works well and I get nicely ordered data with dates and exact time:

```
2018-12-01 00:07:05
2018-12-01 00:09:04
2018-12-01 00:25:42
…
```

1. Question) 
   Is that based on my system-time and therefore my time-zone (CET +1) or do I have to convert it again?

Now let’s say I want to generate x-Minutes chunks (e.g., 30 Minutes) that count how many observations I have in a x-minutes timeframe, like:

```
From | To | Count
2018-12-01 00:00:00 | 2018-12-01 00:30:00 | 3
2018-12-01 00:30:00 | 2018-12-01 01:00:00 | 6
2018-12-01 01:00:00 | 2018-12-01 01:30:00 | 5
…
```

At the same time I have some other numeric variables in my data frame and I want to get the mean in my new x-minutes-chunks-data-frame. (e.g., the first three observations are in the first chunk (= one observation) and here I want to have the mean for each variables of these three observations).

2. Question) 
   Do you have any idea how I can efficiently do that?

Cheers :)

EDIT:

```r
mydf <- data.frame("content" = c(replicate(10,"Here is Text")), 
           "replies" = c(1,2,3,2,5,2,6,2,6,3), 
           "credits" = c(4,7,3,6,2,11,7,10,9,0),
           "unix_timestamp" = c("2018-12-01 00:07:05 GMT", "2018-12-01 00:09:04 GMT", "2018-12-01 00:25:42 GMT", "2018-12-01 00:28:40 GMT", 
                                "2018-12-01 01:09:11 GMT", "2018-12-01 02:19:05 GMT", "2018-12-01 03:29:06 GMT", "2018-12-01 04:06:30 GMT", 
                                "2018-12-01 04:29:06 GMT", "2018-12-01 05:29:16 GMT"))
```

My goal:

```r
data.frame("count" = c(4,0),
           "mean_replies" = c(2,0), 
           "mean_credits" = c(5,0),
           "from" = c("2018-12-01 00:00:00 GMT","2018-12-01 00:30:00 GMT"),
           "to" = c("2018-12-01 00:30:00 GMT", "2018-12-01 01:00:00 GMT"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first question, I have no idea (dates are cumbersome, timezones are worse), it seems to me that if you established `tz = "GMT"`, then that *should* be the timezone.

Regarding your second question, you can do it easily with data.table and `cut()`:

```
# load libraries
library(data.table)

# load data
dt <- fread("1543748345000
1543760946000
1543752164000
1543720144000
1543752713000
1543781064000
1543753688000
1543765145000")

# Convert dates to appropriate format
dt[, V1 := as.POSIXct(as.integer(as.numeric(as.character(V1)) / 1000.0),origin='1970-01-01', tz="GMT")]

# count occurrences by 30 minutes chuks:
dt[, .N, 
     by = cut(V1, 
              seq(as.POSIXct("2018-12-02", tz = "GMT"),
                  as.POSIXct("2018-12-03", tz = "GMT"), 
                  by = "30 min"))]
```

Which results in:

```
                   cut N
1: 2018-12-02 10:30:00 1
2: 2018-12-02 14:00:00 1
3: 2018-12-02 12:00:00 3
4: 2018-12-02 03:00:00 1
5: 2018-12-02 20:00:00 1
6: 2018-12-02 15:30:00 1
```

**######## ADDED TO ADDRESS MODIFIED DATA IN QUESTION #######**

```
cutVector <- seq(as.POSIXct("2018-12-01", tz = "GMT"),
                 as.POSIXct("2018-12-02", tz = "GMT"), 
                 by = "30 min")

mydf[, .(mean_replies = mean(replies), 
         mean_credits = mean(credits), 
         count = .N), 
       by = cut(V1, cuVector)]
```

You still may need to modify / adjust names of variabes, ranges, etc.

It's a good idea reading carefully `?data.table` and `?cut`

Comment: thank you! I didn't know the cut function before and I think that's exactly what I'm searching for. I can run your code but I've problems to fit it to my case since I've never worked with the data.table-library and do not exactly understand the syntax (and I'm not an R-Pro as well^^). I tried it now some hours but I just come up with Error Messages :/ 
Maybe you can take a look at my data frame (I edited the post). I know, my bad, I should have posted the original one right at the beginning but I thought just a hint would be enough for me.

Comment: No worries. I'll have a look once I get close to my machine. I'm far from a computer at the moment.